# Timezone UTC vs Europe/London

Tags: datetime, timezone

An API I am using fetches viewer usage data related to a website, and it has a datetime column set in **UTC** time. The question I have is if I'm reading this from Europe/London timezone, and during **daylight saving** Europe/London time is **+1hr** over **UTC**, in this case, if I have the data as below coming from API:

**DataTime            Viewer**

2023-03-27 07:00:00 400

2023-03-27 08:00:00 400

2023-03-27 08:59:00 400

2023-03-27 09:01:00 400

Should I read/understand/interpret this information this way?

**DataTime            Viewer**

2023-03-27 08:00:00 400

2023-03-27 09:00:00 400

2023-03-27 09:59:00 400

2023-03-27 10:01:00 400

Comment: How does this relate to Azure?

Comment: On March 10th, London will *not* be observing DST. But fundamentally, we don't know whether the API you're calling returns UTC or a local time. You should ask the API provider that. We also don't know what the viewer should actually show... basically there's a *lot* of context missing in this question.

Comment: Hi Jon, Sorry the date was just an example, however I updated to 27 March 2023 during when Europe/London will be +1 hr over UTC. 

The API I'm calling returns UTC time

Comment: Most programming languages and frameworks have facilities to take UTC timestamps and translate them to the timezone you want. You didn't tell us which programming language you use, so it's hard to give you specific advice.

Comment: Okay, so now we know what the API returns. We still don't know nearly enough about how you're going to use the data. Maybe it would be better displayed in UTC. Maybe it would be better displayed in "the local time for that viewer" (if the viewer's time zone is in another part of the data). Maybe it would be better displayed in the time zone of whoever is looking at the data. That's a product question, basically, not a programming one.

Comment: **Yes.** For dates and times after 2023-03-26T01:00Z those are the correct interpretations for Europe/London time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If the API you are calling returns date/time in UTC and you want to show the time in a specific time zone's local time, then you will need to use datetime math to convert the datetime received from the api in UTC to a specific time zone's local time.

Comment: Better than math use a proper date-time library. It will do the math not only more easily but first of all with fewer errors than you will on your own.

Comment: @Ole V.V. - Correct each operating system has a way to manage date/time and most development platforms contain libraries to manipulate datetime values based on the most current time zone information available.